# Using WebRTC to transfer generic data/objects peer to peer?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, real-time-data

I'm just trying to find any demos or instructions of any kind to be able to transfer generic data with WebRTC, such as JSON.

Any [demos/articles](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) I come across only seem to deal with Video transfer which I find bizzare, kindof like running before the ability to walk.

It looks like [this is the api](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#peer-to-peer-data-api) that would be utilised for this task. Does anyone know of how to achieve this, or know of any demos anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it but there this [demo for Firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/progress-update-on-webrtc-for-firefox-on-desktop/)

[This Google I/O video on WebRTC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8C8ouiXHHk) may be of interest although there is no demo of data channels.

Also note that data channels are not implemented as of yet in Chrome (["The Data Channel API is not implemented and its implementation is being discussed in the standards committee"](https://sites.google.com/site/webrtc/faq-recent-topics)), but the aforementioned presentation says they are [due for this quarter](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/16vD-RApRli9W76z36hKe-B3jjS1R-J9qX4lpBq2JrHg/present#slide=id.g4e5bbbc_0_130)